# why can't I compare a string to a string literal?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I have some code that's downloading some strings from a JSON source. One of these is a login success message:

```
{
    login = SUCCESS;
    msgSuccess = "User has been logged-in successfully.";
}
```

So to test this, I did...

```
    if ([[theDictionary objectForKey:@"login"] isEqualToString: @"SUCCESS"]) {
```

That always fails. But if I do this...

```
#define kLoginSuccessMessage                     @"SUCCESS"
if ([[theDictionary objectForKey:@"login"] isEqualToString: kLoginSuccessMessage]) {
```

it works perfectly.

I've never understood why. Especially when you consider that the objectForKey doesn't seem to have any problem. Can someone explain this so I don't pull out what little is left of my hair?

Comment: This doesn't look like a string but more like an enum.

Comment: Somehow I find it rather hard to believe. Are you sure there's no typo in the string literal that you pass to `isEqualToString:`? There must be something else going on.

Comment: If you use the first example (that fails) and put in an `else` clause to log the value of `[theDictionary objectForKey:@"login"]`, what does it tell you?

Comment: Uhhh, I just rolled back and it appears the only difference is a space between the : and the @. But my further attempts to re-create the problem with and without the space have failed, now it works every time. Sorry guys, i think I've wasted everyone's time chasing a gremlin.